# Mask first 3 Characters in the Email with "*"

Tags: c#, string

I would like to mask first 3 Character of email with "*"

eg.

```
abcdefg@gmail.com 

***def@gmail.com

a = abcdefg@gmail.com 
a = a.PadLeft(a.Length  , '*');
```

Thanks

Comment: a = "***" + a.Substring ......

Comment: `a = "***" + string.Concat(a.Skip(3));`

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
int maskCount = 3;
(new String('*', maskCount)) + a.Substring(maskCount)
```

or

```
a.Substring(maskCount).PadLeft(a.Length, '*')
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with the following:

Copy string to new variable (assuming you want to keep the full email address for later),
Have 3 *'s at start of new string and
Use `string.Substring(n)` to grab the rest of the original string

Putting this into a function:

```
private string MaskString(string stringToMask, int charsToMask, char maskingChar = '*')
    {
        string returnString = "";

        //Check the length of the string is larger than the chars to mask
        if(stringToMask.Length < charsToMask)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format(
                    "The number of characters to mask is more than the lenght of the string!\ncharsToMask: {0}\nlength of string: {1}",
                    charsToMask,
                    stringToMask.Length
                )
            );
        }

        //add the masking char the required number of times
        for(int i = 0; i < charsToMask; i++)
        {
            returnString += maskingChar;
        }

        //only add the remaining chars of the original string if the length is less than the no. of chars to mask
        if(stringToMask.Length > charsToMask)       
            returnString += stringToMask.Substring(charsToMask);

        return returnString;
    }
```

This can be used like:

```
public void TestMasking()
    {
    string a = "abcdef@email.com";
    Console.WriteLine("a: {0}", a);
    Console.WriteLine("Masked a: {0}", MaskString(a, 3));

    /*Output:
        a: abcdef@email.com
        Masked a: ***def@email.com  
    */

    Console.WriteLine("a: {0}", a);
    Console.WriteLine("Masked a: {0}", MaskString(a, 5));

    /*Output:
        a: abcdef@email.com
        Masked a: *****f@email.com      
    */
    }
```